# AS3: Is there anyway to tell if connection has been lost during FileReference.upload()?

Tags: actionscript-3, file-upload, filereference

Observing `FileReference.upload()` I notice that if I'm uploading large file (big enough for upload to last for some time) and cut the connection (by pulling out LAN cable for example) in the middle of upload, Flash doesn't report an error... In fact it continues to fire Progress events all the way to "successful" completion.

Is this a bug? Shouldn't there be an exception thrown or error event fired?

Answer (score 1):

Accordning to the documentation on FileReference.upload() it should invoke an IOErrorEvent when such a thing happens.

Try listening for an IOErrorEvent

```
yourFilereference.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, error)
function error(e:IOErrorEvent):void
{
    //Do something
}
```

Comment: I do, but it doesn't help :)

Comment: hmm, can you try listen to all different type of events that upload() can have? such as HTMLStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS etc

Comment: I do listen to all of them. But as I say only Progress events continue to fire.